# what is 現地では市民 and does the sentence lose it original meaning if we change it to 現地の市民

Tags: words

クーデターから2年を迎える1日、現地では市民が外出を控える「サイレント・ストライキ」と呼ばれる抗議活動が行われる予定です。
https://news.tv-asahi.co.jp/news_international/articles/000285667.html

Answer (score 2):

現地では means "at the location/site" and 市民 basically means "people (citizens)."

We could translate 現地では市民が外出を控える as "In the area, people avoid going out."

現地の市民 would mean citizens (people) of the area/location (that the article concerns).

So we could translate 現地の市民が外出を控える as "Local people avoid going out."

In this case, the structure would be changed but the two sentences happen to mean practically the same thing.